# Pulling dictionaries from html file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working with this URL:

`https://fiaresultsandstatistics.motorsportstats.com/results/2021-monaco-grand-prix/session-facts/0976b01f-e26a-420f-a6e9-3371897fc88b?fact=LapTime`

so far I've done this to isolate the text I want.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
all_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
ftext = all_scripts[5]
```

Here's an example of what I want to pull.

```json
[
    {
        "carNumber": "10", "driver":
        {
            "name": "Pierre Gasly",
            "uuid": "pierre-gasly",
            "code": "GAS",
            "picture": "https:\u002F\u002Fcontent.motorsportstats.com\u002FdriverProfilePicture\u002FdriverProfilePicture-7c13a1b1-029d-4d59-80ad-861a17b16872.jpg",
            "type": "Driver"
        },
        "laps": [
            {"lap": 1, "time": 86902},
            {"lap": 2, "time": 78737},
            {"lap": 3, "time": 77821},
            ... same for all other laps...

            {"lap": 78, "time": 76120}
        ]
    }
]
```

Then I just have to repeat 19 times. I figured this is too big for regex and don't really know what else I can use to pull this out.

Comment: Please provide some code that people can actually run to obtain the text you currently have in `ftext`. What have you done to process that text into a dictionary yourself at all? Are you asking where to start such a conversion? Can you share a (partial) example of the text, to explain why you're having trouble doing it? It looks like you're scraping the scripts, not the generated document - that probably means you'll have to parse through the JS in there, why not get the data from the rendered page, if you're scraping anyway?

Comment: If you only want the data and this is not for a school project which focusses on web scraping or something similar you can use the non-commercial [ergast API](http://ergast.com/mrd/) which will provide you with all that information. The format obviously differs a bit but it has nice docs (as far as I could see at first glance) and provides the data you need - for free. To write a program which is webscraping all that data from the official F1 stats site will take forever in comparison to just using the API. And I believe there's no free offical API for fans.

Comment: This [https://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/2/laps/1.json](https://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/2/laps/1.json) for example will give you the lap times of all drivers in lap 1 of last weeks GrandPrix in Saudi Arabia in a nice JSON format which you can parse using `json.loads()` and you will have your dictionaries with all the data. There also is a [Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/11586746/SztEa7bL) with sample requests.

Comment: @Mushroomator you are a legend thank you! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use findall() on specific attributes like findall(_class = "car") or findall(id="driver") you will have to inspect the HTML to be specific and you can also use regex to pull specific strings out like this:

```
def ElementsWithRegexByClass(soup: BeautifulSoup, class_string: str):
    return soup.find_all(class_=re.compile(class_string))

and call it like this:

class_string = "driver"
class_elements = ElementsWithRegexByClass(soup, class_string)
```

You can then use the class_elements to construct a list or something and in the end combined all the attributes you want into a JSON file.
I definitely recommend looking through the BeautifulSoup documentation

I get the soup content like this:

```
def GetMeTheSoup(url):
     page = requests.get(url)
     return BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
```

so you can assign, soup = GetMeTheSoup(#Your url)

Comment: Ooh nice, I didn't think of extracting it from the HTML!

Comment: I tried this but it didn't call anything

Comment: I will edit my post to show how I get the soup content

Comment: I made your edit. However, when I call class_elements it returns [] . Is there something I'm supposed to put in front of it or does it not see my inputs as a class?

Comment: from that site you would need to use class_string = "_2sWDi f4AjL" or "_1TRrV"

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: Nvm I found it after searching. This is my first webscrape so I'm a little lost haha

Comment: no worries, I have worked a lot with beautiful soup so feel free to keep asking questions!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to send a HTTP GET request to that URL. I've taken the liberty of Using `Inspect Element` (Usually one of the `FN` keys, `F11` on Firefox which is what I use) to verify that it returns a JSON - which it does!

Specifically the action you want to take - `fact` is specified as a query at the end of the URL: `http://...?fact=LapTimes`

Python has utilities to work with both HTTP requests returning JSON - namely the `requests` package that does both for you. We'll start by importing that and setting up our parameters:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

query_field = "fact"
query_param = "LapTime"
your_url = "https://fiaresultsandstatistics.motorsportstats.com/results/2021-monaco-grand-prix/session-facts/0976b01f-e26a-420f-a6e9-3371897fc88b"
```

Now that we've got our data, we can create our request URL from this; it fits the format `{your_url}?{query_field}={query_param}` which we can use verbatim with a Python `fstring`:

```
request_url = f"{your_url}?{query_field}={query_param}"
```

We can leverage the `requests` package to do the HTTP request for us and return the result as a `dict`, and then check that the request was successful:

```
lap_time_request = requests.get(url=request_url, params={}) # No GET parameters specified

try:
    lap_time_request.raise_for_status() # Raises an error if status != 200 (success)
    lap_times = lap_time_request.json()
except HTTPError as e: # If status != 200
    # handle errors here
    # maybe do something with invalid response?
    response = e.response
    print(f"Could not retrieve response {reponse.status_code=}")

# print(lap_times) => "[{"carNumber":"10","driver":{"name":"Pierre Gasly","uuid":"pierre-..."
```

**EDIT**

As an aside before I get to the solution, I was looking through the JavaScript and found this gem in there:

```
__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED: {
    ReactCurrentDispatcher: k,
    ReactCurrentBatchConfig: T,
    ReactCurrentOwner: C,
    IsSomeRendererActing: {
        current: !1
    },
    assign: n
}
```

So I guess somebody *might* be getting fired unless its a honeypot?

**Actual Edit**

In this specific example, it looks like the request is actually being *referred* first - we can get around that by looking at the request header, which looks something like this:

```
GET /web/3.0.0/sessions/0976b01f-e26a-420f-a6e9-3371897fc88b/lapTimes HTTP/2
Host: fiaproxy.motorsportstats.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: https://fiaresultsandstatistics.motorsportstats.com
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://fiaresultsandstatistics.motorsportstats.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
TE: trailers
```

If we save that to some file `request.txt` we can use the [burpee](https://github.com/xscorp/Burpee) library, it's one small file that you can just add to your project:

```
import burpee

# gets data from file if you want to inspect it
# headers, data = burpee.parse_request("request.txt")
# burpee handles doing the get and returns a `requests.Reponse`
lap_time_response = burpee.request("request.txt", https=True)

try:
    lap_time_response.raise_for_status() # Raises an error if status != 200 (success)
    lap_times = lap_time_response.json()
except HTTPError as e: # If status != 200
    # handle errors here
    # maybe do something with invalid response?
    response = e.response
    print(f"Could not retrieve response {reponse.status_code=}")

# print(lap_times) => "[{"carNumber":"10","driver":{"name":"Pierre Gasly","uuid":"pierre-..."
```

Comment: I could just be missing something but I'm getting an error JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: I did a big search and figured it out, tested to work this time!